# Flutter: getting related data from tow collections in Firestore

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have tow collections in Firestore (Users - Villages)..

Users: has in each document (id - name - email - village - ..)

Villages: has in each document (id - name).

I want to check which user has signed in, and know his village, then fitch the village data from "Villages" collection.

I typed this code, but some thing not completed !!!

```
AuthController authController = AuthController();

String? id;
String? village;
List<UserModel> items = <UserModel>[].obs;

matchCollections() async {
  var currentUserEmail = authController.auth.currentUser!.email;
  await userCollectionRef
      .where('email', isEqualTo: currentUserEmail)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    for (var item in value.docs) {
      id = item.id;
      print(id);
      items.add(UserModel.fromMap(item));
    }
    for (var index in items) {
      village = index.village;
      print(village);
    }
  });
}

test() {
  print(village); // return "null" result
  return villagesCollectionRef
      .where('name', isEqualTo: village)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((event) {
    for (var i in event.docs) {
      print(i.id); // return all documents ids for this collection
    }
  });
}
```

As I preview in the code, the variables (id - village) when I use them in "matchCollections()" function I could reach the data, but when I use them in "test()" function I had 'null' value for each one.

The goal of this code is to know if this user from "XXX" village, and show the data which it related to his village, because "Villages" collection has documents and each one of them has subCollection.

Comment: Please set the debugger in this line. I believe the village isn't filled
 village = index.village;

Comment: @AmirMohammadShams
```I/flutter (13037): 3PpQSSN6UMSY3u4zBEaloUwcntp1
   I/flutter (13037): "Azaz"
```
This is what appears in the console by run this function (this to prints orders)
the first is print(id), and the second is print(village).

Comment: When you call matchCollections, Do you put await before matchCollections ?

Comment: No, without putting await it prints the last message. But the test function print null, which means variable village doesn't store the value.

Comment: @AmirMohammadShams By the way, I putted "matchCollections()" in initState(), so when the app is starting, it begins automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reached to the solution finally, I made a new class controller then call it in the main() directly.

It works good..

```
class MainController extends GetxController{
  static MainController instance = MainController();

  final CollectionReference villagesCollectionRef =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Villages');

  final CollectionReference userCollectionRef =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');

  String? userColId;
  String? userVillage;
  String? idOfVilCol;
  List<UserModel> items = <UserModel>[].obs;

  matchCollections() async {
    var currentUserEmail = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;
    await userCollectionRef
        .where('email', isEqualTo: currentUserEmail)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      for (var item in value.docs) {
        userColId = item.id;
        items.add(UserModel.fromMap(item));
      }
      for (var index in items) {
        userVillage = index.village;
      }
      test(userVillage);
    });
  }

  test(String? value) async {
    await villagesCollectionRef
        .where('name', isEqualTo: value)
        .get()
        .then((item) {
      for (var i in item.docs) {
        idOfVilCol = i.id;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Here where I call it:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null){
    await MainController.instance.matchCollections();
  }
  await initialServices();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```